# Can I account for an unknown starting period while estimating reliability?

Tags: r, distributions, modeling, reliability, censoring

I have been going through this [article](http://quanterion.com/ReliabilityQues/V2N2.html) on how to estimate the reliability of a device using Weibull Analysis. The article clearly states that in order to do this, I need to have information in the following form:

```
#   Age_A   Age_B
1    26      16
2    31      24
3    35      30
4    38      36
5    41      42
6    44      48
7    47      55
8    51      63
9    55      76
10   70      126
Avg. 44      52
```

From my understanding, this age must have been measured from some **starting period** that is used as the experiment starting time. Now, if I am not really sure of the experiment starting point and have observations of failures across time, is there any way I can still carry out the Weibull Analysis to draw some conclusions?

To put it clearly, let us say that in the middle of nowhere I decide to see which type is more reliable while both types have been operational for an unknown period of time. My idea was to fix a time period `t` and then start calculating the age relative to this `t`. Of course, the serious drawback is for devices that have been operational for a long time that fail right after `t` in which case the age is miscalculated at a small number. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have what's called left-censored data. Survival likelihoods are still computable for it, although are even more complicated than for right-censored data, so I am not going to attempt to reproduce them here. [Klein and Moeschberger's book](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=jS2Cy0lezJIC&oi=fnd&pg=PR5&dq=left+censored+survival+analysis+weibull+regression&ots=wnWhXfZsEo&sig=7wwRNikx3JBSroJw0vpwo3DHfnI#v=onepage&q=left%20censored%20survival%20analysis%20weibull%20regression&f=false) covers Weibull regression in a couple of sections, and [NADA package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NADA/index.html) provides some of the tools of the analysis of left-censored data.

Comment: Paul Allison's book *Survival Analysis Using the SAS® System: A Practical Guide* covers how to analyze data like this in SAS as well. I would try to see if you can try and find the starting time (origin) of your measurements before you go with this approach, as it's considerably more complex.

Comment: @EpiGrad: Thank you for your suggestions. My problem is that even if I do determine the starting time for the measurements, they will be different for different devices and missing for most of them.

Comment: @Legend You go with the data you have then - its harder to model censored observations, but far from impossible. Good luck!

Comment: @EpiGrad: I am currently bound to R so am not really sure how much of this is really far from impossible :) Are you aware of any material that discusses this using R?

Comment: @Legend: have you taken a look at NADA package I suggested? This is an R package alright.